# declaring two properties with different name that will point to the same variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

In general I would like to have to properties with different name to point to the same variable.

The reason for that is that I want my class to conform to MKAnnotation and I want the title property to have the same value as my other property called name and it's pretty important for me not to change the name of my original property (name).

Is there a smart way to do so without having two objects and just cloning one into the other?

Comment: Have two properties that point to the same variable.  `@synthesize a=var; @synthesize b=var;`

Answer (score 2):

The problem with HotLicks' and TheSaad's answers has to do with Key-Value Observing (KVO) compliance.  If something is observing your `name` property, you need them to be informed if something else calls the `setTitle:` setter.  And vice versa.

I would recommend `@synthesize`-ing one of your properties as usual.  For example, I'll assume that `name` is done that way.  Then, you need to make the other, `title` in this case, pass through to that property plus tell KVO about the dependency:

```
- (void) setTitle:(NSString*)newTitle
{
    self.name = newTitle;
}

- (NSString*) title
{
    return self.name;
}

+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingTitle
{
    return [NSSet setWithObject:@"name"];
}
```

For an understanding of that last method, read the docs for [`+[NSKeyValueObserving keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002299-SW4).

You can't just `@synthesize` both to point to the same ivar (e.g. `_name`) and then provide just the `+keyPathsForValuesAffectingTitle` method to inform KVO that `title` depends on `name`, because that won't let observers of `name` know when `setTitle`: has been called.  You may be tempted to fix that by also providing `+keyPathsForValuesAffectingName` to tell KVO about the dependency in the other direction. I don't think that works and I wouldn't depend on it even if it seemed to in experiments. It's prone to either infinite recursion or the frameworks simply ignoring the circular dependency (to avoid the infinite recursion).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of synthesizing you need just write your own accessors for the  properties. You can do so as follows.

In your interface:

```
@interface Student
{
    NSString *_name;
}

@property (readonly, nonatomic) NSString *firstName;
@property (readonly, nonatomic) NSString *lastName;

@end
```

In your implementation:

```
@implentation Student

- (NSString *)firstName
{
    return _name;
}

- (NSString *)lastName
{
    return _name;
}

@end
```

Note: This will cause issues with Key-Value Observing if mutation occurs as the observer will only be notified about the method being called, not the mutation of the actual value.

Answer (score -2):

```
yourObject.firstProperty = [[AClass alloc] init];  // ---> alloc or set to an existing object...

yourObject.secondProperty = yourObject.firstProperty;
```

this way both properties points to the same allocated object